# Does "The Lost Canvas" OVA have a sequel?

Tags: saint-seiya

I watched the two OVAs of "The Lost Canvas" (26 episodes at total). But the story didn't end. Is there a sequel of this OVA series? If yes, can you please name them?

Comment: Saint Seiya is a series to sell toys, mangas and other animes. So the hype is part of producer's intention to hold watchers. The canon is the way they maintain the property of the hyped object and what represents a risk for the producers is out of canon. XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [My Anime List](http://myanimelist.net/anime/9130/Saint_Seiya:_The_Lost_Canvas_-_Meiou_Shinwa_2), the sequel to the Lost Canvas OVAs is [Saint Seiya's TV series](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1254/Saint_Seiya). Also, [this image of the timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2sEV.jpg) seems to back up that claim, though I don't know who created the image.

Answer (score 2):

The original *Saint Seiya* series is not the actual continuation nor is *The Lost Canvas* the prequel to it, it is a spin-off of the original series, it's posed on an alternative timeline from the actual continuation to the original series which is *Saint Seiya: The Next Dimension*.

If you want to continue that specific spin-off, you should read the manga and gaidens it has.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read *Saint Seiya: The Lost Canvas* in the manga version because it has much more details about the sequel.

There are 25 volumes of the manga version, and the end of the last volume also talks about 243 years later that continue to *Saint Seiya*.

Answer (score 1):

They never ended the anime run of *Saint Seiya: The Lost Canvas* due to the low ratings in Japan.

There have been multiple requests from the fans, for them to finish *The Lost Canvas* anime, but they have been ignored.

You could read the manga.